# Minimal Url and view for static pages on django

Tags: django

The app I am creating has many static pages, just like the pages of a website which do not change for some time. Im my model I will have a title field and a text field. I am looking go a way to avoid multiple views and multiple urls for each page. I tried using flatpages, but I was not able to get to work the context processors. For example, if a certain page has many grids. So how to write a single view and a url which will deliver all the pages, along with the context processors.

Comment: Flatpages seems to fit the use-case you describe well. So maybe focus on the context processor problem, which is just mentioned, not explained.

Comment: As flatpage templates are inbuilt, it is difficult to add items such as copyright notice, and elements which should appear on each page.

Comment: any context processor you have defined should be available in the template you are using to render flatpages

Comment: @nixotwin what? Flatpages templates are *not* built in. You have to provide them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having problems with flatpages, it's not hard to write your own version!

**models.py**

```
from markdown import markdown

class CustomFlatPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','myapp.views.customflatpage', name='customflatpage'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
def customflatpage(request,slug):
page = get_object_or_404(CustomFlatPage, slug=slug)
    return direct_to_template('path/flatpage_template.html',
        extra_context={
            "page":page,
        })
```

**template** (has access to request context etc.)

```
{{ page.title}}
{{ load markup }}
{{ page.body|markdown }}
```

Use TinyMCE on the body field in django-admin (if you are using it) or your own form if you want rich text.